# Error when adding data from an asynchronous request to a WebSQL database

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, cordova, web-sql

I am building an application for Android using Phonegap / Cordova which uses the device calendar. I've written a plugin ("Calify") that adds events to the device calendar which works fine. However I'm trying to add the device calendar event ID, which the plugin returns, to a record in an Web-SQL database, but this gives me the following error(s) (running in the Android simulator):

```
file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.2.0.js: Line 1090 : processMessage failed: Message: S01 Calify507282772 s[{"id":191,"calid":615}]
file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.2.0.js: Line 1091 : processMessage failed: Error: Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
```

Here's what my code looks like.

```
window.addEvent(function(insertions){
    data = JSON.parse(insertions);
    console.log(insertions);
    event_id = data[0]['calid'];
    id = data[0]['id'];

    tx.executeSql('UPDATE AFSPRAKEN SET eventID=? WHERE id=' + id, [event_id]);
}, [calendarID, [{start: start.getTime(), end: end.getTime(), title: event_title}]]);
```

The log of 'insertions' gives me the desired result, as well as logging 'event_id' and 'id' individually. It seems to have something to do with the database insertion (which is asynchronous as well).
Note that this function runs within a database transaction, which is needed because I'm running some other queries as well outside this calendar event function. Commenting out the insert query makes the code run without errors.

DOM Exception 11 seems to mean the object ('insertions' I guess?) is no longer accessible, perhaps it has something to do with that.

Comment: I've managed to get around this by adding the parameters of addEvent to an array, which I iterate when the database transaction is successful. In the itaration the addEvent function is run which creates a new database transaction on completion to update the corresponding record(s). A definate answer explaining the original behaviour would still be welcome, but my guess is that it's caused by the asynch request (addEvent function) embedded in another asynch request (db transaction), with the completion of the former request trying to run something within the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake I made is pretty obvious now, so for everyone finding this question through Google (the error message is not really pointing in the right direction) here's why my code gave the errors:

The database transaction is asynchronous, as well as Phonegap plug-ins. The Phonegap function compeletes outside the database transaction, making it impossible to run database queries inside that transaction. This could be solved in several ways:

- Open a new database transaction in the complete function of the Phonegap communication
- Like I did, connect with the Phonegap plugin after the database transaction